# My QGIS install fail - Installation must be on a local hard drive

Tags: qgis, installation

QGIS will not install:

> Installation directory must be on a local hard drive

I tried V3.32 and V3.28 with the same result. I tried creating the destination directory to see if that was the problem but got the same result.  The primary drives on my system are all SSDs and I tried all of them. I also tried a USB connected drive. All attempts gave the same error.  I disconnected all network drives to see if the installation was confused by their presence but that had no effect.  Just for grins I tried installing to a network drive. The installation hung at that point.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
System info

OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 11 Pro
OS Version:                10.0.22621 N/A Build 22621
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
Registered Owner:          kkroeker
Registered Organization:   N/A
Product ID:                00331-20300-00000-AA628
Original Install Date:     10/12/2022, 10:26:40 AM
System Boot Time:          7/18/2023, 9:21:16 AM
System Manufacturer:       SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER
System Model:              HX90
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: AMD64 Family 25 Model 80 Stepping 0 AuthenticAMD ~3301 Mhz
BIOS Version:              American Megatrends International, LLC. 5.19, 8/5/2021
Windows Directory:         C:\WINDOWS
System Directory:          C:\WINDOWS\system32
Boot Device:               \Device\HarddiskVolume1
System Locale:             en-us;English (United States)
Input Locale:              en-us;English (United States)
Time Zone:                 (UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
Total Physical Memory:     28,595 MB
Available Physical Memory: 18,765 MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size:  51,810 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 36,447 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    15,363 MB
Page File Location(s):     C:\pagefile.sys
Domain:                    KEN
Logon Server:              \\KJK-RYZEN
Hotfix(s):                 4 Hotfix(s) Installed.
                           [01]: KB5028851
                           [02]: KB5012170
                           [03]: KB5028185
                           [04]: KB5028320
Network Card(s):           7 NIC(s) Installed.
                           [01]: TAP-NordVPN Windows Adapter V9
                                 Connection Name: Ethernet 6
                                 Status:          Media disconnected
                           [02]: VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
                                 Connection Name: VirtualBox Host-Only Network
                                 DHCP Enabled:    No
                                 IP address(es)
                                 [01]: 169.254.116.209
                                 [02]: fe80::f6d5:8748:8:505c
                           [03]: Intel(R) Ethernet Controller I225-V
                                 Connection Name: Ethernet 5
                                 DHCP Enabled:    No
                                 IP address(es)
                                 [01]: 192.168.1.70
                                 [02]: fe80::77ff:285f:3b1e:1886
                           [04]: Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz
                                 Connection Name: Wi-Fi
                                 Status:          Hardware not present
                           [05]: VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
                                 Connection Name: VMware Network Adapter VMnet8
                                 DHCP Enabled:    Yes
                                 DHCP Server:     192.168.220.254
                                 IP address(es)
                                 [01]: 192.168.220.1
                                 [02]: fe80::403f:949d:925e:2289
                           [06]: Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
                                 Connection Name: Bluetooth Network Connection
                                 Status:          Media disconnected
                           [07]: VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
                                 Connection Name: VMware Network Adapter VMnet1
                                 DHCP Enabled:    No
                                 IP address(es)
                                 [01]: 192.168.80.1
                                 [02]: fe80::aeef:7a11:2ef4:1180
Hyper-V Requirements:      A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed.
```

Answer (score 1):

this seems to be unrelated to QGIS.
Apparently, you need to run the installation manually using the CMD terminal. This is the solution recommended by [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMWVBLX2ols), [this other video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q1rL9eSAJaw), and [this article](https://communities.bentley.com/products/site_analysis/w/site_analysis_wiki/31561/installation-directory-must-be-on-a-local-hard-drive).

TL-DR: Run the Command Prompt as Admin, then type:

```
msiexec /i [C:\Path\To\Your\Installer]
```

The command itself is basically asking Windows to perform a normal installation, see [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/msiexec) for more information.

You can also change directory to get to the file: in the command prompt, type

```
cd [C:\Path\To\Your\Installer]
```

then run the setup file (this is shown in the second video link).

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response - installed OK now.